# Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I have two different videos which I'm trying to load into a `VideoView` using

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
```

The two videos, let them be *video 1* and *video 2*, have the following specs (extracted using `ffmpeg -i`); in fact, they are two different encodings of the same video:

1. Video 1:

   ```
   Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4fbfd5ece4b0932236fc234d.mp4':
     Metadata:
       major_brand     : mp42
       minor_version   : 0
       compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
       creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
       genre           : Trailer
       artist          : Paramount Pictures
       title           : Captain America: The First Avenger - Theatrical Trailer #2
       encoder         : HandBrake 4344svn 2011111001
       date            : 2011
     Duration: 00:02:30.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6738 kb/s
       Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x800 [PAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 6575 kb/s, 23.97 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
       Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 159 kb/s
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
   ```
2. Video 2:

   ```
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '500416ea44aeb4b95d5ae8a0_hd.mp4':
     Metadata:
       major_brand     : isom
       minor_version   : 512
       compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
       creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
       title           : Captain America: The First Avenger - Theatrical Trailer #2
       artist          : Paramount Pictures
       date            : 2011
       encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
       genre           : Trailer
     Duration: 00:02:30.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2045 kb/s
       Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 27:20 DAR 12:5], 1889 kb/s, 23.99 fps, 90k tbr, 180k tbn, 180k tbc
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
       Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 151 kb/s
       Metadata:
         creation_time   : 2011-12-03 04:43:46
   ```

I am aware that AAC support came with Honeycomb, and therefore I tested the videos with several devices; the results are given below:

1. `SGS II with custom 4.0.3 OS(Sensation ROM 3.4 with CF-Root kernel) - Video 1:OK - Video2:OK`
2. `SGS I with Samsung 2.3.3 OS - Video 1:error (1, -2147483648) - Video 2:OK`
3. `SGS I with custom 4.0.3 OS(ICS SGS TEAM ROM with Devil kernel) - Video 1:error (1, -2147483648) - Video 2:OK`
4. `Nexus One with original 2.3.6 OS - Video 1:See (1) below - Video 2:See (2) below`
5. `Emulator with 2.2 OS - Video 1:error (1, -2147483648) - Video 2:error (1, -2147483648)`
6. `Emulator with 4.0.3 OS - Video 1:error (1, -2147483648) - Video 2:error (1, -2147483648)`

Both videos play fine in Google Chrome in a PC. It might be useful to add that in the OK case, video and audio both play correctly. In the error (1, -2147483648) case, the same log is spewed from all devices (except Nexus One):

```
07-18 10:25:10.996: I/MediaPlayer(17860): uri is:http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-k6ohn88yswx5-eu-west-1/videos/4fbc88e7e4b0b0896e877764/4fbfd5ece4b0932236fc234d.mp4
07-18 10:25:10.996: I/MediaPlayer(17860): path is null
07-18 10:25:10.996: D/MediaPlayer(17860): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-18 10:25:39.859: D/MediaPlayer(17860): getMetadata
07-18 10:25:45.070: E/MediaPlayer(17860): error (1, -2147483648)
07-18 10:25:45.074: E/MediaPlayer(17860): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-18 10:25:45.078: D/VideoView(17860): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

In the (1) case, the following log is spewed from Nexus One, and the video never loads:

```
07-18 13:49:20.115: D/MediaPlayer(10109): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-18 13:49:20.115: I/StagefrightPlayer(68): setDataSource('http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-k6ohn88yswx5-eu-west-1/videos/4fbc88e7e4b0b0896e877764/4fbfd5ece4b0932236fc234d.mp4')
07-18 13:49:20.135: I/NuHTTPDataSource(68): connect to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:80/cf-templates-k6ohn88yswx5-eu-west-1/videos/4fbc88e7e4b0b0896e877764/4fbfd5ece4b0932236fc234d.mp4 @0
07-18 13:49:20.155: I/ActivityManager(98): Displayed com.woisio/.video.VideoActivity: +450ms
07-18 13:49:20.795: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:22.185: I/OMXCodec(68): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 4 buffers of size 460800 on input port
07-18 13:49:22.195: I/OMXCodec(68): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 8 buffers of size 2304000 on output port
07-18 13:49:25.325: D/dalvikvm(9499): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 50% free 2726K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 116ms
07-18 13:49:27.525: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:28.235: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Cache full, done prefetching for now
07-18 13:49:30.275: D/dalvikvm(9902): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 50% free 2714K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 69ms
07-18 13:49:34.255: D/Finsky(9066): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
07-18 13:49:35.855: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:39.055: D/dalvikvm(9911): GC_EXPLICIT freed 22K, 50% free 2710K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 38ms
07-18 13:49:42.575: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:43.285: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:44.095: D/dalvikvm(9918): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 50% free 2708K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 66ms
07-18 13:49:49.085: D/dalvikvm(9925): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15K, 49% free 3268K/6407K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 50ms
07-18 13:49:50.925: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:54.115: D/dalvikvm(6756): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 44% free 3774K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 77ms
07-18 13:49:57.685: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:58.375: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:49:59.105: D/dalvikvm(9066): GC_EXPLICIT freed 385K, 53% free 3186K/6727K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 66ms
07-18 13:50:05.955: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:50:06.045: D/dalvikvm(8047): GC_EXPLICIT freed 9K, 47% free 3830K/7111K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 86ms
07-18 13:50:09.465: I/3gw.Service(488): Mobile Network not connected - not roaming
07-18 13:50:12.765: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:50:13.465: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:50:18.775: I/WindowManager(98): Setting rotation to 3, animFlags=0
07-18 13:50:18.795: I/ActivityManager(98): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=286/2 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=34}
07-18 13:50:18.895: D/dalvikvm(169): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 108K, 48% free 3253K/6215K, external 5172K/5180K, paused 37ms
07-18 13:50:21.005: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:50:21.265: D/dalvikvm(98): GC_EXPLICIT freed 394K, 42% free 6631K/11335K, external 4458K/5567K, paused 109ms
```

In the (2) case, the following log is spewed from Nexus One and as you can see, ends with an error (1, -2147483648):

```
07-18 13:47:03.595: D/MediaPlayer(10059): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-18 13:47:03.595: I/StagefrightPlayer(68): setDataSource('http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-k6ohn88yswx5-eu-west-1/videos/4ff4514444aec3d2f9f07ead/500416ea44aeb4b95d5ae8a0_hd.mp4')
07-18 13:47:03.605: I/NuHTTPDataSource(68): connect to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:80/cf-templates-k6ohn88yswx5-eu-west-1/videos/4ff4514444aec3d2f9f07ead/500416ea44aeb4b95d5ae8a0_hd.mp4 @0
07-18 13:47:03.625: I/ActivityManager(98): Displayed com.woisio/.video.VideoActivity: +505ms
07-18 13:47:05.355: I/OMXCodec(68): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 4 buffers of size 460800 on input port
07-18 13:47:05.355: I/OMXCodec(68): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 8 buffers of size 1382400 on output port
07-18 13:47:05.365: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:47:08.375: D/MediaPlayer(10059): getMetadata
07-18 13:47:08.745: D/dalvikvm(9925): GC_EXPLICIT freed 651K, 49% free 3275K/6407K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 68ms
07-18 13:47:09.205: I/3gw.Service(488): Mobile Network not connected - not roaming
07-18 13:47:11.565: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Cache full, done prefetching for now
07-18 13:47:12.095: I/NuCachedSource2(68): Keep alive
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): H264_Utils::check_header 
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): check_header: start code 33
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): H264_Utils::check_header 
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): check_header: start code 10
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): Parsing Error unsupported profile or level
07-18 13:47:14.245: W/QCvdec(68): ETB in Invalid State
07-18 13:47:14.245: E/OMXCodec(68): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] ERROR(0x8000100a, 0)
07-18 13:47:14.245: E/MediaPlayer(10059): error (1, -2147483648)
07-18 13:47:14.285: E/MediaPlayer(10059): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-18 13:47:14.285: D/VideoView(10059): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

From what I have read, the error (1, -2147483648) may correspond to unsupported codecs, corrupt metadata or incorrect file headers. If it is so, could you point me in the right direction as to use which codec? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the videos streaming on all the devices? Can you please share your findings with me? I am having the same problem. The videos work on few devices and on a few they don't.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Just to clarify something for anyone reading this question based on the title.

When looking at the error value (1, -2147483648), the '1' value corresponds to the constant in [MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN).

-2147483648 corresponds to hexadecimal 0x80000000 which is defined as UNKNOWN_ERROR in frameworks/native/include/utils/Errors.h

This shows that the error's source is hard to pin down as it is quite a generic return value, thrown by codec and compatibility issues as mentioned above but also thread cancellations and several other types.

For your issue, I would recommend consulting the [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) with compatible Android versions and see if the encoding type is the cause of your problem, but as mentioned above the Unknown Error response can be caused by a number of problems.

Comment: What is the solution? Don't have? I don't understand clearly what u mean. So Only need change `encoder` or should remove `encoder`?

Comment: @MirrorTowers: In my case, on some devices I didn't have the permission to read the files even though it was my app who created them, after downloading them from a server and putting them in the app's cache folder. Try changing the read permissions.

Comment: I received this error when streaming a resource from https on 3.0. It seems HTTPS is only supported from Android 3.1 onwards

Comment: As an update - this is now also explicitly defined as 'MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM (-2147483648) - low-level system error.' in the Android online documentation for MediaPlayer (at the time of writing): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html - doesn't necessarily help that much but at least it is there explicitly...

Answer (score 34):

I was facing the same error on Android P (Pixel 2 XL), but all I had to do was put `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on my `AndroidManifest.xml` application tag.

Comment: Can't help you with that. MediaPlayer is not reliable, I would like to recommend you to use ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 7):

For streaming, the Android site has a note:

> For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat
>   atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom.

I got the same error before moving the `moov` atom. In order to fix this, you can use [mp4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) with this command:

```
MP4Box -hint output.mp4
```

Most of my videos can stream after that. If it does not work, try this with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec libfaac -ar 16k -ab 32k output.mp4
MP4Box -hint output.mp4
```

There are other tools you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidVideoEncoding).

Answer (score 2):

I am also getting same **MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN** error issue for playing video(rtsp).

In my case I am finding issue with my wifi. Some security reasons wifi is restricted for RTSP protocol. So that I'm facing this MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN error issue. Once check with your network permissions.

When I am moving to mobile data for playing video it's working fine for me.
May be this will be helpful whoever facing same kind of error :).

Answer (score 2):

Take care of the support media type and resolution of your device. 
Error `error (1, -2147483648)` often, appear when your video media type, codecs, or resolution is not supported by your device.

Checkout the media type supported by Android in the documentation :

https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

For example, we can notice that device above 3.0 support .mp4, but not all of them support HD 720p.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `MediaPlayer` for playing audio, this was the case of error for me:

When performing `.setDataSource()` the argument I passed was a string with path to the given file. This results in all kind of exceptions I havent been able to find particular reasons for. However, when changed to `FileDescriptor`, according to [Android Developers - .setDataSource() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor,%2520long,%2520long)), its sorted out.
I am getting the `FileDescriptor` object from `FileInputStream`.
Here is the code:

```
val player: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
fun playRecording() {
    try {
        replayFileStream = FileInputStream(path)
        val fd = replayFileStream?.fd
        player.setDataSource(fd)
        player.prepareAsync()
        // start should be called from onPreparedListener
     } catch (e: Exception) {
        // catch exceptions
     }
 }
```

The actual start of the playback is handled in `OnPreparedListener` as suggested for example here: [Android Media Player: Start called in state 4 error(-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516469/android-media-player-start-called-in-state-4-error-38-0)
.
The listener setup is following:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(object: MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    override fun onPrepared(player:MediaPlayer) {
        player.start()
    }
})
```

[android](/questions/tagged/android) [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) [mediaplayer](/questions/tagged/mediaplayer)

Comment: can you describe  in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case the video would play fine when I downloaded it to the phone first and then played it. But when I tried to use Progressive HTTP I would get the same error noted in the OP.

I verified that the ftyp, moov and mdat atoms were in the correct order. It turned out that the problem was the the value of the ftyp field. It was set to 'qt  '. I used MP4Box to extract the tracks and create a new mp4 file which had the ftyp set to 'isom'. This new file worked fine for Progressive HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this similarly to the way stated in @nam-trung's answer, however as my videos were already **h264** and **mp4** all I needed to do was run the following on each file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vprofile baseline output.mp4
```

After that, the videos all worked in *VideoView* when run on all devices I've tested on running API v19 through v25.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was due to the mediaplayer not having file permissions on the locally stored video. Try storing the video onto the `/mnt/sdCARD` directory.

Comment: I cannot store the video, it must be streamed from an external server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue ,But what i did on my side is

Firstly i stop the media player and then Released it.

mMediaPlayer.stop();
  mMediaPlayer.release();

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had Gzip Compression on the web address where the url info is. Compressed media files may not be decoded on android.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this problem was caused by a media URL with spaces!  Here is the fix:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(source.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
```

Comment: The Android Universal Media Player app (UAMP) does this. The fix to get it working for URL's like those at cbsrmt.com is correctly shown above.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using firebase , then you should copy the path(or url) from 1: Download Url which contains the https://firebasestorage.............

not from the storage location

2 :  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`add this permission   in manifest tag inside manifest folder

inside Rules of storage

inside Rules of storage :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
 allow read, write: if true;
  }  
 }  
 }
```