# Android MediaPlayer Error - (1, -2147483648)

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am fetching data from a web service, that contains list of .mp4 files as url's
The problem that arises is out of 10. Seven of the .mp4 files are played and the other remaining three when played says "The video cannot be played" and when i check the log the media played throws out an error 
11-14 10:50:44.710: E/MediaPlayer(10091): Error (1, -2147483648)
Please can any one help out by what type of an error is this. As i read people saying it about permissions. But am accessing via a web service that gives me the data.

Thanks.

Comment: dominic You just refer this Link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833537/android-mediaplayer-videoview-error-1-2147483648

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648