# Encoding video for Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

How do I properly encode video for Android?  I've seen [the supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations) but I don't really know where to start with producing a video with those settings.

I'm not yet streaming these videos.  These are just for local playback.

What's the correct process for encoding videos to maximize compatibility across Android devices?

Comment: http://handbrake.fr/  So easy peasy.

Comment: What's your video source?  Some examples using MediaCodec with AVC: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: My video source is Android MediaRecorders, but they all seem to record in different formats, despite my CamcorderProfile and MediaRecorder settings.  I need a way to normalize these videos such that they're playable across Android devices, regardless of which device they were recorded on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the line that I use to convert videos suitable for Android.  I've had good luck playing it on all devices running Android >= 4.  Note that this matched the "high quality" parameters in the [recommended video encodings](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations).

```
avconv -i source.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -b 500k -r 30 -vf "setsar=1:1" -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k converted.mp4
```

The [setsar](http://libav.org/avconv.html#setsar) filter I use sets the sample aspect ratio to 1:1, which I've found to be helpful if you're also using any of the [transpose](http://libav.org/avconv.html#transpose) or [scale](http://libav.org/avconv.html#scale) options.

For example, to rotate the video clockwise, use this:

```
avconv ... -vf "transpose=dir=clock, setsar=1:1" ...
```

One thing to keep in mind is that some devices don't support playing videos with a resolution larger than a screen.  That is, a phone with a screen size of 400x800 may have a hard time playing your video that's 800x600.

To rotate counterclockwise and scale your video such that its width is 400:

```
avconv ... -vf "transpose=dir=cclock, scale=400:trunc(ow/a/2)*2, setsar=1:1" ...
```

To rotate clockwise and scale your video such that its height is 400, use this:

```
avconv ... -vf "transpose=dir=clock, scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:400, setsar=1:1" ...
```

I hope this helps!  It's been a lot of trial and error for me.

For what it's worth, here's the avconv I'm using:

```
avconv version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:36 with gcc 4.6.3
```

And I've installed [this libav-tools package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libav-tools) and [this libavcodec-extra-53 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libavcodec-extra-53).