# Android VideoView throws Error: 1,-2147483648 trying to play a video from sd card

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard, android-videoview

I want to play a video from my sdcard on my android device inside a VideoView but I always get the **Error: 1,-2147483648**. My code looks like this:

```
private VideoView video_view;
private MediaController ctlr;

//define video and play it if it exists
    File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            +feed.getStep(current_step).getPathToVideo());

    if (clip.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Video exists");

        video_view.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

        ctlr = new MediaController(this);
        ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video_view);
        video_view.setMediaController(ctlr);
        video_view.requestFocus();
        video_view.start();
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Video DOES NOT exist, path is: "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath()+feed.getStep(current_step).getPathToVideo());
    }
```

In LogCat I get this output:

```
Video DOES NOT exist, path is: /storage/sdcard0/video/lvl1/documentariesandyou.mp4
```

The video is located at my sdcard in `/video/lvl1/documentariesandyou.mp4`

The video is compatible I took it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516707/1582279).

What can I do to play the movie on my device?

Comment: Refer this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833537/android-mediaplayer-videoview-error-1-2147483648?rq=1

Comment: Hello, how you can fix this issue? Please update answer. Thank you Mr.Mojo.

Comment: @HuyTower: I have posted the solution as comment in the marked answer. My SD card was mounted from my OS (Ubuntu) so Android couldn't mount it.

Comment: Where is this `marked answer`? This one "The problem was that the storage was mounted by my OS (ubuntu) and so I could not access the files on the sdcard! " ??? I don't understand what u said. Not related to Android device? no need modify codes or permission, something else related to Android device?

Comment: Yes the problem was not the code, the problem was that I already mounted my SD card inside my operating system. After I dismounted it from Ubuntu, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your manifest have a [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.
2. Check the availability of the external storage using [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29).
3. Try `getAbsolutePath()` instead of just `getPath()`.

Comment: 1. The permission is set 2. The status is "mounted" 3. Also no solution using getAbsolutePath()

Comment: The problem was that the storage was mounted by my OS (ubuntu) and so I could not access the files on the sdcard!

Comment: i want to play video url