# Android TV VideoView strange error code

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-tv

Im coding an player application for Android Tv. 
While testing to play videos on a nexus player device the VideoView (that is a wrapper of MediaPlayer) is giving me some strange error codes that are not documented at all in the api references. 
My nexus player is api 23 (android M) and i also target api 23 in my app.

Here is the log:

```
10-21 15:42:59.234 29145-29145/com.test.androidapp D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
10-21 15:42:59.259 29145-29734/com.test.androidapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147479543)
10-21 15:42:59.260 29145-29262/com.test.androidapp E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
10-21 15:42:59.265 29145-29145/com.test.androidapp E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147479543)
10-21 15:42:59.265 29145-29145/com.test.androidapp D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147479543
```

Comment: -2147479543 indicates unknown error and there could me many possibilities on what went wrong.  These might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833537/android-mediaplayer-videoview-error-1-2147483648

Comment: Try using Google's ExoPlayer instead. It is more robust: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/