# Android MediaPlayer error codes (-103 / -105)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm going crazy with Android Media Player.

The same code works on some devices but fails with different error codes on other devices.

I'm trying to figure out what error (1, -103) and error (1, -105) mean but didn't find no documentation on this.

i have a wrapper class that controls a media player object but this is how it translates:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/");

   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
  mediaPlayer.prepareAsnyc();
```

On Samsung Galaxy SIII i'm getting an -1004 error which after a depth search found out that it might be a winamp Shoutcast Streaming problem.

On a different device i get the -103 and -105 errors and i can't find what they mean.

i tried to add an errorlistener and return true but it doesn't work.

```
            m_mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Can you please help ?

THanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

-1004 is documented on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). It reads as MEDIA_ERROR_IO, which states File or network related operation errors. Which directs you to the stream, as you are using http.

The other two I don't know though..

Answer (score 0):

Most of Android's errors follow linux error codes.
-103 means connection aborted, mostly you get when there is network connectivity needed but not available.
-105 means no buffers available. if your app tries to read from network source, you may get these two.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my app and I'm still looking for the answer, all I've found so far is the video format causes this problem, 
Take a look at these links :

[Android VideoView Cannot play video mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451180/android-videoview-cannot-play-video-mp4#)

and

https://superuser.com/questions/489087/what-are-the-differences-between-h-264-profiles

All i got is we should change the H.264 profile and set it to baseline. I'm still looking for the way to convert it in the app, not on the server !