# Flutter player wont play audio from podbean

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio

guys, I'm building a music app in flutter and I have a problem which I don't know how to resolve, so if someone can help me out on this.

So this is the thing I have songs that are stored on CloudFront and they work perfectly

```
 play(song, context) async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(song); //path to the song
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = true;
    });
    // int seek = await audioPlayer.seek(Duration(minutes: 10, seconds: 10));
    if (result == 1) {
      return 'succes';
    }
  }
```

but when I give another path from podbean it will not start playing "https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/play/9i7qz8/Japji_Sahib_Pauri_3.mp3" -> this is the link you can play it in browser

[Error message. Shows after some time on the initial play of the podcast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYpFB.png)

Any idea what I can do about this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Media Player: Start called in state 4 error(-38,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516469/android-media-player-start-called-in-state-4-error-38-0)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, but I don't have functions like that in the flutter. Or maybe I'm not good enough.

Comment: Well, you should add what they mentioned in the answers to your code.

Comment: can you give me some more hint?  Thanks