# VideoView Cannot Play Video on Galaxy S2

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, video-encoding

I am using a VideoView to play a video in my app and it works fine on the Galaxy S3, Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 but it fails to play on the Galaxy S2.  I get a popup that says "Sorry, this video cannot be played."  and in the LogCat I get:

`11-07 10:44:16.052: E/MediaPlayer(5781): Error (1,-2147483648)`

Which, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648), means nothing really.

> When looking at the error value (1, -2147483648), the '1' value
>   corresponds to the constant in MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN.
>
> -2147483648 corresponds to hexadecimal 0x80000000 which is defined as UNKNOWN_ERROR in frameworks/native/include/utils/Errors.h

I have tried two different mp4 encodings and a 3gp encoding and it's the same situation.  Works on all devices expect the Galaxy S2.  Has anyone had this problem before and been able to find a solution?

Comment: samsung lacks in this field are huge

Comment: Also having this issue.  Would love to hear if you've found any answers since asking this question.

Comment: Nope, never did figure it out!  We just marked the S2 as an unsupported device!