# Get `MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)` when try to play video file after created immediately from sd card

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, video-recording

I already read many answer from same questions, like [`the answer for same question but looks like still not find out the solution` from sturrockad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648)

I'm working on `Custom Camera with Recording video feature` now.

I can `take picture and then review picture correctly`.

But have `issue with record video and then review video immediately`.

I want to `play video after record video immediately` via parameter `FILE_PATH`, not be in the next time open app.

I already tried :

1 - Scan media mounted for Android system recognized new files appear.

2 - Try `put fixed File Path, it worked`, can be played. `"/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_143003.mp4"`. But this way not be what I want.

People who know how to `play video after record video immediately` via parameter `FILE_PATH`,

Please tell me,

Thanks.

p/s :

- My case is Play video directly from sd card after recording video successfully, not stream video from server.
- Android 4.1 - Sony Xperia U.
- Only my application can not play video immediately after recording video successfully. If play video by using default Media Player application (the other application) is OK.
- The other thing, please notice, If used Fixed File Path can play existed video.

**ERROR**

`MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)`
`MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)`

**LOGCAT**

```
I/ExternalStorage﹕ Scanned             /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_153645.mp4:
I/ExternalStorage﹕ -> uri=content://media/external/video/media/21992
I/﹕ FILE_PATH /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_153645.mp4
E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

**EDIT** I got the answer. Thank you.

**BELOW THE CODE PLAY VIDEO**

```
private void showVideoOnUI() {
    Log.i("", "FILE_PATH " + FILE_PATH);

    // THIS LINE SHOW THE VIDEO TOTALLY CAN BE PLAYED
    //        mVvVideo.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_143003.mp4");

    // ------- ERROR HAPPEN IN THIS LINE ---------
    // FILE PATH = /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_143555.mp4 also,
    // BUT THE VIDEO TOTALLY CAN NOT BE PLAYED
    mVvVideo.setVideoPath(FILE_PATH);
    //        mVvVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(FILE_PATH));

    // set play video view dialog details photo
    MediaController mMc = new MediaController(getActivity());
    mMc.setAnchorView(mVvVideo);
    mMc.setMediaPlayer(mVvVideo);

    mVvVideo.requestFocus();
    mVvVideo.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mVvVideo.setMediaController(mMc);
    mVvVideo.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    mVvVideo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (mVvVideo.isPlaying()) {
                mVvVideo.pause();

                // Show full-screen button again
                mVvVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mVvVideo.start();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    if (!mVvVideo.isPlaying())
        mVvVideo.start();
}
```

**BELOW IS THE CODE SCAN MEDIA TO SEE NEW FILE AFTER CREATED**

```
/**
 * Create a File for saving an image or video
 */
private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), define.Camera.ENTERPRISE);

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i("", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = null;
    if (type == MediaType.PHOTO) {
        mediaFile = new File(
                mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + Extension.JPG);
    } else if (type == MediaType.VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(
                mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_" + timeStamp + Extension.MP4);
    }

    String FILE_PATH = mediaFile.getAbsolutePath();
    // todo Should refresh Sd card in here
    File mFile = new File(FILE_PATH);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), mFile.getName());
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        Log.i("", "contentUri - " + contentUri.toString());

        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } else {
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + mFile.getParent())));
    }

    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(),
            new String[]{FILE_PATH}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    // ExternalStorage﹕ Scanned /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Enterprise/VID_20150327_151212.mp4:
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    // ExternalStorage﹕ -> uri=content://media/external/video/media/21973
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    return mediaFile;
}
```

**HERE IS MANIFEST.XML FILE**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".Enterprise"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="ui.activity.CustomCamera"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ui.activity.CustomGallery" />

</application>
```

**HERE THE CODE TRANSFER TO REVIEW PAGE FROM RECORDING VIDEO PAGE** [CORRECT]

```
/**
                 * Record video mode
                 */
                // Begin Record video

                // Configure MediaRecorder
                if (IS_RECORDING_VIDEO) {
                    Log.i("", "Stop recording video");

                    try {
                        // stop recording and release camera
                        // stop the recording
                        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.stop();

                        // release the MediaRecorder object
                        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
                        // take camera access back from MediaRecorder
                        CustomCamera.mCamera.lock();

                        // inform the user that recording has stopped
                        IS_RECORDING_VIDEO = false;

                        // Stop the preview before transfer to Review page
                        CustomCamera.mCamera.stopPreview();

                        // Should release Camera for the next time can be used
                        CustomCamera.releaseCamera();

                        // Transfer to Review page to see Recording video at there
                        // Send the file path also
                        ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                                .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .replace(
                                        R.id.fl_custom_camera,
                                        CameraReviewFragment.newInstance(
                                                getOutputMediaFile(MediaType.VIDEO).getAbsolutePath()))
                                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // initialize video camera
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder(define.Camera.CAMERA_BACK)) {
                        Log.i("", "Start recording video");

                        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                        // now you can start recording
                        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.start();

                        // inform the user that recording has started
                        IS_RECORDING_VIDEO = true;

                        // Begin set Recording time in here
                        //start the countDown
                        mCdt.start();
                    } else {
                        // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
                    }
                }
```

**HERE THE CODES SET UP RECORDING VIDEO**

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(int mode){
    // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
    CustomCamera.releaseCamera();

    // Initialize camera
    CustomCamera.mCamera = CustomCamera.getCameraInstance(mode);

    // Set orientation display
    CustomCamera.setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(), mode);

    // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
    CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();

    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    CustomCamera.mCamera.unlock();
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(CustomCamera.mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // todo Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    //        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    //        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    //        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    // Step 4: Set output file
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MediaType.VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**FINALLY** I recognized my fault. Sorry for all. I need edit the code as below

```
// Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    RECORDED_FILE_PATH = getOutputMediaFile(MediaType.VIDEO).toString();
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(RECORDED_FILE_PATH);
```

AND

```
// Transfer to Review page to see Recording video at there
                        // Send the file path also
                        ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                                .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .replace(R.id.fl_custom_camera,
                                        CameraReviewFragment.newInstance(RECORDED_FILE_PATH))
                                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648)

Comment: @maven I already read the answer. It looks like the recommend, advice indicate that related to something as Encoder ... not actually be the solution, isn't it? What do you think? Or you understand the answer indicate what? Please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: there is no direct solution you have to verify the video format recorded and make it [compatible with the encoder](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: `"video format recorded and make it compatible with the encoder"` - Actually default Media player can play my recorded video. So it is not enough? As I said in my question, my app only can not play it immediately after recording video successfully. If I passed `fixed File Path` value, it totally can be played. Wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution now.

It is my fault. I called `getOutputMediaFile()` method 2 times, so it created 2 files :

- 1 File have data by using stream to transfer. [THIS FILE MY APP NOT READ]
- 1 File not have data [THIS FILE MY APP READ]

Therefore, `video can not play` dialog was shown, and I also get this error `MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)`

p/s : I hope I contribute the reason explain why We get this `UNKNOWN_ERROR`.

Sorry for all,

Thank you.