# Error in WindowManager (In Service): Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-service, android-videoview, android-windowmanager

I know there are many questions regarding this error in SO, but my problem is different. I am trying to play a video from sdcard in videoview. VideoView run on WindowManager with serivce. So the app is able to play the video on top of any application. Every thing is working, I could able to play video. But there is corrupted file in my phone which is not getting played in any other video players. It will say error reading the file.But when I opened that video file with my app which run in service now then comes the issue, APP is CRASHING. I am not able to catch the problem so as to Toast error reading the video file. I tried with

```
   videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

did not work.

CODE:

```
public class VideoWindow extends Service {

     private WindowManager windowManager;
     private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
     WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
     private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;
     private View mLayout;
     DisplayMetrics metrics;
     private boolean didFling;
     private int[] clickLocation = new int[2];
     private static final String LOG_TAG = "Floaty";
     private float ratioY = 0;
     private float oldWidth = 0;
     private float oldX = 0;
     private boolean confChange = false;
     private VideoView videoView;
     private ProgressBar progressBar;
     private int position = 0;
     private String videoUrl;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("OnStartCommandStarted", "true");
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    confChange = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("confchange");
    oldX = intent.getExtras().getFloat("oldX");
    ratioY = intent.getExtras().getFloat("ratioY");
    oldWidth = intent.getExtras().getFloat("oldWidth");
    videoUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("videourl");
    position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");
    windowManager.removeView(mLayout);

    if (confChange) {
        confChange = false;
        Log.d("Configure change","true");
        if (oldX < (oldWidth / 2)) {
            params.x = 0;
        } else {
            params.x = metrics.widthPixels;
        }
        params.y = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * ratioY);
    } else {
        params.x = metrics.widthPixels;
        params.y = 0;
    }
    windowManager.addView(mLayout,params);
    playVideo();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("OnCreate Started", "true");

    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,new Gesture());
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mLayout=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.smallwindow, null);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.body);
    videoView = (VideoView)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoloadprogress);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


    params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP| Gravity.START;


    Log.d("Configure", String.valueOf(confChange));

    relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                relativeLayout.setAlpha(1.0f);
                if (!didFling) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ACTION_UP");
                    int newX = params.x;
                    if (newX > (metrics.widthPixels / 2)) {
                        params.x = metrics.widthPixels;
                    } else {
                        params.x = 0;
                    }
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(mLayout, params);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    windowManager.addView(mLayout, params);

}


private void playVideo(){
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });


    try{
        Log.d("videoUrl",videoUrl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error reading file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.seekTo(position);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            } else if(position>0) {
                videoView.start();
                videoView.seekTo(position);
                position=0;
            }else{
                videoView.pause();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        int[] location = new int[2];
        mLayout.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        oldWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            oldX = location[0];
            ratioY = (float) (location[1]) / (float) metrics.heightPixels;
        this.stopService(new Intent(this, VideoWindow.class));

        confChange=true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoWindow.class);
        intent.putExtra("confchange",confChange);
        intent.putExtra("oldX",oldX);
        intent.putExtra("ratioY",ratioY);
        intent.putExtra("oldWidth",oldWidth);
        intent.putExtra("clickLocation",clickLocation);
        intent.putExtra("videourl",videoUrl);
        intent.putExtra("position",videoView.getCurrentPosition());
        this.startService(intent);
        Log.d("OnConfigurationChanged","true");
    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


private class Gesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private int initialX;
    private int initialY;
    private float initialTouchX;
    private float initialTouchY;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDown");
        initialX = params.x;
        initialY = params.y;
        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
        didFling = false;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onShowPress");
        relativeLayout.setAlpha(0.9f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (relativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        params.x = (initialX + (int) ((e2.getRawX() - initialTouchX)));
        params.y = (initialY + (int) ((e2.getRawY() - initialTouchY)));
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(mLayout, params);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed");

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFling");
        didFling = true;
        int newX = params.x;
        if (newX > (metrics.widthPixels / 2))
            params.x = metrics.widthPixels;
        else
            params.x = 0;
        windowManager.updateViewLayout(mLayout, params);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoWindow.class));
    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLayout != null){
        windowManager.removeView(mLayout);
    }
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
10-11 19:18:29.911 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-11 19:18:29.922 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Left Align: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Width Align: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Top Align: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Height Align: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Min ROI Width: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Min ROI Height: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Needs ROI Merge: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Dynamic Fps: Disabled
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Min Panel fps: 0
10-11 19:18:29.927 6268-6302/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/qdutils: Max Panel fps: 0
10-11 19:18:32.696 6268-6546/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-11 19:18:32.696 6268-6546/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-11 19:18:32.759 6268-6546/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
10-11 19:18:34.624 6268-6735/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer I/ListingVideos:  query count=9
10-11 19:18:34.624 6268-6735/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/videos: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Onamalu Telugu Full Movie HD - Rajendra Prasad _ Kalyani _ Kranthi Madhav_HIGH-mc.mp4
10-11 19:18:34.673 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/Loaded: true
10-11 19:18:34.685 6268-6759/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-11 19:18:34.686 6268-6759/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
10-11 19:18:34.719 6268-6759/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
10-11 19:18:38.832 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/OnCreate Started: true
10-11 19:18:38.868 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/Configure: false
10-11 19:18:38.878 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/OnStartCommandStarted: true
10-11 19:18:38.902 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/videoUrl: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/Onamalu Telugu Full Movie HD - Rajendra Prasad _ Kalyani _ Kranthi Madhav_HIGH-mc.mp4
10-11 19:18:38.971 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-11 19:18:39.022 6268-6289/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
10-11 19:18:39.056 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
10-11 19:18:39.056 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
10-11 19:18:39.140 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-11 19:18:39.141 6268-6268/com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.ficean.floatingvideoplayer, PID: 6268
                                                                          android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:583)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
                                                                              at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                              at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                              at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)
                                                                              at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:537)
                                                                              at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2592)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
```

Comment: that´s not the complete error stacktrace, there must be more with a reference to the code where the problem is

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I posted complete stacktrace, please look at it

Comment: not, there must be more after that you have posted.....not before. I guess you have set some filter in logcat...

Comment: Edit your question, post the `windowManager.addView` method, and all the related info. You are adding a null `View`, or inserting into a null `windowManager`... in any case, it is a logical failure.

Comment: @Bonatti, Added Code please check.@Opiatefuchs there is nothing after the error in stacktrace

Comment: You never checked if `mLayout` is not null, before adding on `windowManager.addView(mLayout, params);` Also, you are adding in `onCreate`, then changing in `onStartCommand`. If this only happens when the movie loaded is "corrupt", then your issue is not the `View`, but a another used one: `at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)` It is likely a `null View` was added in the body of the message to be displayed. It appears to be originated from the `playVideo();` after `windowManager.addView(mLayout,params);` in `onStartCommand`...

Comment: I found the problem, it is beacuse of `E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)`. So the next error is causing . But I did not figure out how to catch it. Do you have any idea of this kind of unknown error?

Comment: Please, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18084143/4903925)