# Streaming Video from URL and show in VideoView

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I have little problem with streaming videos from "URL".
I am using **"Camera Streaming"** application which opens camera and give me URL like **"192.168.0.??:8080"**.
And I can stream that video in browser in my PC.

Now my question is that **how can I stream that video in my application into VideoView**.

**I tried opening video in videoview using "setVideoURI()"** but it's saying "Can't play this video." and giving me error in logcat like :

1) D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648

2) E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

3) D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Can you help me stream videos in VideoView ?

Thanks in Advance!
Darshan Popat

Comment: It seems the video is hosted on local server..so your device should be in same network to play the video where server is hosted locally

Comment: Yes Burhanuddin Rashid,
My both devices are on same wifi connection.
Still not able to play.

Comment: How about [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)?

Comment: @WadeTyler INTERNET is also working.

Comment: @DarshanPopat What do you mean by "it's working"? Is it working now?

Comment: As I told in question that I am able to load video in PC browser and Mobile browser as well. It's just not playing in VideoView.

Comment: @DarshanPopat What I meant by that link, is that you should check to see if you have added the INTERNET permission in your app's manifest.

Comment: @WadeTyler
Yes sir I have added Internet permission in Manifest file.

Comment: @DarshanPopat Check this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648) out. The format of the video you're trying to play is not supported. Try using ExoPlayer.

Comment: Have you added `http://` before the url ??? @DarshanPopat

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid
Yes sir, 
I have added.