# How to fix video in gallery from not playing (probable cause encoding from ffmpeg)

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I'm setting up a video stream by which I can download a video into the Android gallery, so that I can play it back later.
I have a problem with playing the video back from gallery. The same problem arises when trying to view the url in a videoview.

video information from ffmpeg displays this.

```
Input #0, mpjpeg, from '':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1cab5e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x1c6f030] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x1c6f030] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x1c6f030] 264 - core 157 r2969 d4099dd - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.33.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x406, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.59.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
Error opening file out.mp4: IsoMedia File is truncated28.56 bitrate= 734.1kbits/s speed=0.478x
[pid: 5138|app: 0|req: 1/1] 192.168.178.21 () {32 vars in 406 bytes} [Mon Oct  7 01:12:17 2019] GET /stop => generated 39 bytes in 152 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
frame=  899 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2779kB time=00:00:29.93 bitrate= 760.6kbits/s speed=0.49x
video:2775kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.157041%
```

I have attempted to follow this article. [Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648)

I'm using FFMpeg to record from a mjpeg stream into a file, which then is hosted by a uwsgi/flask server into a convenient url: http://ipaddress/video.mp4

Thus far ive been able to open the video fine using chrome in Android.

my FFMPEG command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -crf 18 -r 30 -vf "scale=720x406, setpts='1/(30*TB) * (N + 0.05 * sin(N*2*PI/25))', fps=fps=30" -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -preset fast out.mp4
```

I thought it may have something to do with the transmission of the file. I'm using an android library called volley to send the url so it can be downloaded as a file on the Android. Then it is subsequently put in gallery. This is when I began to experience the problems. I wanted to be thorough, so tried to find out if the file contents was the issue. This is because when displaying it on gallery, there is no width or height information, or even duration. I have come to suspect something is at issue with ffmpeg. I'm not cutting out that it could be keeping the file from opening if it can't find it's normal file properties.

The volley code for the downloaded file is as follows:

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
        try {
            if (response!=null) {

                File file = createVideoFile();

                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    stream.write(response);
                } finally {
                    stream.close();
                }

                addToGallery(file.getAbsolutePath());
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, (path, uri) -> {
                    Intent intent = new Intent (context, VideoActivity.class);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);

                });


                Toast.makeText(this, "Download complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("KEY_ERROR", "UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void addToGallery(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{

                        path},

                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)

                    {

                        Log.e(TAG, "file" + path + " was scanned successfully");

                    }

                });

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
```

I did have a VideoView to display it, as pertaining to a code example i found to download videos using volley.

https://github.com/coderminion/AndroidVolleyLib