# Android MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648) audio from url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I try to play an audio mar form url I receive the error: E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)

Here is my code:

```
public void playAudio(final String url){
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uri);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This error most probably related to incorrect URL or is not a supported format.
I suggest you looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648

Comment: I tried with .mp3 format and .m4a but neither work