# VideoView cant play the video file and shows mediiaplayer error

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I want to play a video, an error occurs like, Can't play this video. am using android 10.
Error (1-2147483648)

What can be? I'm missing any permission or something else?

My code is:

```
package com.example.touristguide;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    Spinner events;
    VideoView mumbaiV;
    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mumbaiV = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String event[] = {"Sports", "Events"};

        events = findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<> 
       (this,R.layout.spinner_text_view,event);

        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text_view);
        events.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        mumbaiV = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.touristguide"+R.raw.mum);
        mumbaiV.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mumbaiV);
        mumbaiV.setVideoURI(uri);
        mumbaiV.start();

    }
}
```

***Logcat:***

```
2020-09-09 12:39:28.638 16705-16752/com.example.touristguide E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2020-09-09 12:39:28.672 16705-16738/com.example.touristguide W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2020-09-09 12:39:28.684 16705-16738/com.example.touristguide E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory
2020-09-09 12:39:28.687 16705-16705/com.example.touristguide E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
2020-09-09 12:39:28.688 16705-16705/com.example.touristguide D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Thank You.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648

Comment: Have tried it but this ain't resolving my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you have provided lacks a simple `/` character. So use this path:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.touristguide"+"/"+R.raw.mum);
```

Comment: And for this i had searched Whole Internet. Thanks!