# Android 7 MediaPlayer Error (1,-2147483648)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, rtsp, android-7.0-nougat

I'm trying to make a screen with a video stream from videcam in RTSP. I use MediaPlayer with SurfaceView but also I tried to use VideoView and none of that works on Android 7 (sdk 24), on other versions my code works great.

**Here's the code:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
private var vidHolder: SurfaceHolder? = null
private var vidSurface: SurfaceView? = null
private var progress: ProgressBar? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    vidSurface = findViewById(R.id.videoView)
    progress = findViewById(R.id.progress)
    progress?.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    vidHolder = vidSurface?.holder
    vidHolder?.addCallback(this)
}

override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (!mediaPlayer!!.isPlaying) mediaPlayer?.start()
        } else {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(CAMERA2_URL)
            mediaPlayer?.setOnPreparedListener(this)
            mediaPlayer?.setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(
                    AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE
                ).build()
            )

            mediaPlayer?.prepareAsync()
        }
        mediaPlayer?.setDisplay(vidHolder)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
    progress?.visibility = View.GONE
    mediaPlayer?.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mediaPlayer?.release()
}

override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {}

override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {}
}
```

**Here's  the full log when I start the app on android 7 device:**

```
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.rtspcameratest-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
I/art:     at void com.example.rtspcameratest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:30)
I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rtspcameratest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rtspcameratest-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2678)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:787)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
I/art:     at void com.example.rtspcameratest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:30)
I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa9305240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9305240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9303520)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9305240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9303520)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

**My rtsp stream config:**
h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 704x576, 15 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc

When I start it on android 7.0 it shows Error (1,-2147483648). Previously it didn't work on android 5 either, but we changed profile to Baseline and everything went fine everywhere (even on Android 7.1) except for android 7.0. I've tried some solutions from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648), but nothing helped. Also I've tried to use VLC lib and that fixed android 7 problem, but it weights smth about 80 mb in apk, and that's too much for my app.

I think the problem is somwhere in stream config, but really can't figure out what exactly it could be... And that android 7 situation seems kinda strange for me because there is nothing special about the android 7 in the [official info](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-codecs), maybe you know what it is?

So have you had any similar problem with rtsp? Do you know how to configurate rtsp stream for android in a proper way? What can be the problem with that exact Android 7 version? What can I try to make it work? Any help appreciated!

---

### Update

I made it work by using [ExoPlayer lib](https://github.com/portizb/ExoPlayer/tree/dev-v2-rtsp), but that took some time for me to do, and anyway my project gained weight (not that much as with vlc though). I still don't understand why doesn't the default Android MediaPlayer work, and if a solution appears, I will defenitely return mediaplayer code, because it's just much more simple than exoplayer.

Answer (score 0):

In your (Module) build.gradle file , drop the following conf in the end after dependencies {...}

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == "androidx") {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that doesn't seem to change anything.. Still got the same logs and error.

Comment: "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" was added in  is api28,

Inject the class in debug mode to ignore error message:
{
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version"
//inject class when api<28 && debug==true
debugImplementation 'com.github.DonaldDu:FixUnhandledEvent:1.0'
}

Hopefully this gives a result