# cant play raw video in android studio using java

Tags: java, android

why i cant play raw video in my app? did i miss something in my code? everytime i click the name of video in my listview this error appear in my logcat **2020-11-22 12:34:40.306 8395-8426/com.ncf.fitnessandexercise E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2020-11-22 12:34:40.325 8395-8395/com.ncf.fitnessandexercise E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)** and

this

[image]

```
public class Zumba extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> videoList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zumba);
        videoView=findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.lvideo);
        videoList= new ArrayList<>();
        videoList.add("Basic_Zumba_Steps_for_Quick_Weight_Loss_Fitness");
        videoList.add("Closer_Zumba_Live_Love_Party");
        videoList.add("Senorita_Zumba_Dance_Fitness");
        videoList.add("Short_Zumba_Dance_Workout_for_Beginners");


        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,videoList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video2));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video3));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video4));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(Zumba.this));
                videoView.requestFocus();
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ncf.fitnessandexercise.Zumba">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoview">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This could be helpful for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-2147483648 corresponds to UNKNOWN_ERROR in frameworks/native/include/utils/Errors.h

This shows that the error's source is hard to pin down as it is quite a generic return value, thrown by codec and compatibility issues as mentioned above but also thread cancellations and several other types.

you can use android exoplayer, it supports most of the video format

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'
```

create player

```
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
```

Build the media item.

```
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
```

Set the media item to be played.

```
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
```

Prepare the player.

```
player.prepare();
```

Start the playback.

```
player.play();
```

[github.com/google/ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

[related question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540076/android-mediaplayer-error-1-2147483648)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using non supported video format, have a look at VideoView supported formats: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Incase if your video format is not supported, you can use ExoPlayer https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Please try running it on a physical device, not an emulator.